# My app has a TreeView whose events are "connected" programmatically to RichTextBox. Events in UI are being processed twice. How to prevent this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm working on a Windows Forms app that follows a classical layout with a tree view on the left and a content panel (rich text box) on the right. It keeps a track of what is being typed in the Textbox in real time by parsing the text and updating the nodes in the TreeView.

At the same time I'd like to allow the user clicking on something on the left and highlight the corresponding parts of the text on the right.

My prototype was starting to work but then in step debug mode I noticed that a click on the right panel (which tries to select the corresponding node on the left view by simulating a mouse click on it), was triggering a new update on the right panel, in practice it triggers a two-passes recursion, so every user action on the UI is causing a double processing.

```
private void treeViewMsg_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    initiatedBy = ClickInitiatedBy.TreeViewControl;  // a possible workaround... 
      
    flagNodeSelected = true;
    int caret_pos = richTextMsg.SelectionStart;

    richTextMsg.SelectAll();
    richTextMsg.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
    richTextMsg.SelectionFont = richTextMsg.Font;

    string[] s = null;
    if (e.Node.Level == 2)
    {
        s = e.Node.Parent.Tag.ToString().Split('|');
        richTextMsg.Select(int.Parse(s[1]), int.Parse(s[2]));
        richTextMsg.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextMsg.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextMsg.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(230,230,230);

        UpdateStatusBarInfo(e.Node);
    } else
    {
        UpdateStatusBarInfo(null);
    }
    s = e.Node.Tag.ToString().Split('|');
    richTextMsg.Select(int.Parse(s[1]), int.Parse(s[2]));
    richTextMsg.SelectionBackColor = e.Node.Level==2 ? Color.Lime : Color.FromArgb(230, 230, 230);
    if (!IsCaretVisible())
    {
        richTextMsg.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    flagNodeSelected = false;
    richTextMsg.Select(caret_pos, 0);

    initiatedBy = ClickInitiatedBy.None;
}
```

In this current version I added a class member

> enum ClickInitiatedBy

to track the origin of the event but didn't know what to do with it.  Alternatively I could write something like this:

```
private void treeViewMsg_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if( call_counter == 0 ) {    // class member, visible on all UI methods
        call_counter++;
        
        do_something();

        call_counter--;
}
```

but I preferred to check here if anyone suggests a more "modern" approach or there is already a standard pattern to deal with this problem.  Thanks in advance.